# angularjs select scope doens't update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, scope

I am trying to read out a dropdown, in my view I have the following code:

```
<p class="createT">Timeout</p>
    <select id='timeout' ng-model="jiotimeout" class="createIn form-control">
        <option value='30'>30 minutes</option>
        <option value='60'>1 hour</option>
        <option value='120'>2 hours</option>
        <option value='180'>3 hours</option>
        <option value='360'>6 hours</option>
        <option value='720'>12 hours</option>
</select>
<br>{{jiotimeout}}
```

Then in my controller I have:

```
$scope.jiotimeout = "30";
```

When I change the value in the view the {{jiotimeout}} is succesfully updated with the new value.

However when I make a function behind a button click like the following in the controller:

```
$scope.createdSuccessfully = function () {
     alert($scope.jiotimeout); 
}
```

The alert keeps saying 30 and doesn't update while the value is updating in the view. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You code looks perfect and it should work ; Please provide plunker or fiddle of your problem so we can see what is exactly happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you have given in the question, it should work. Since you have not given the controller, here is the working [`Plunker`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/8d7uo94y/)

**JS:**

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.jiotimeout = "30";

});
```

Comment: I am such a stupid, I tried to put it myself in plunker and realized I didn't include the controller properly. Thank you for the help.